# How to make a bootable HDD with GRUB2

Tags: grub2

I have a (non-UEFI) Gentoo Linux system, and I am preparing a hard drive for another system. I have prepared partitions for the new system, and now I want to make it bootable. I remembed that in legacy GRUB, I used these commands:

```
# grub
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd1)
```

This made a bootsector on current (hd1), which pointed to (hd0). Then, when I booted the system, the new disk became the first device (i.e. hd0) and everything worked.

The only thing I was able to find for GRUB2 is `grub2-install /dev/sdb`, which installs the MBR pointing to UUID of some current volume, which of course fails when I move the disk to a new machine.

So, how do I make a bootable HDD with GRUB2?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that as GRUB2 uses UUIDs for partition ID, all you have to do is mount target `/boot` partition somewhere (let's say `/mnt/new-boot`) and then tell that to GRUB using `--boot-directory`:

```
grub2-install --boot-directory=/mnt/new-boot /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Just doing `grub-install` won't be enough, you will have to `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig` unless you have your own initial `grub.cfg`. I have to run this from a chroot jail for it to work. Here is a snippet adapted from a script I wrote to do this (altered form is untested):

```
# assumes /dev/sdb1 is the target root and
# /boot doesn't have to mounted separately
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdb

mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
chroot /mnt update-grub
umount /mnt/proc /mnt/sys /mnt/dev
```

`update-grub` may be Debian specific, according to the manual it is just a stub for:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: I already had a working `grub.cfg`, but it's good to know this for future reference.